# convert yyyymmdd to dd MMM yyyy

Tags: ms-access

Is it possible to convert date 4 digit year 2 digit month and 2 digit day to dd (3 digit month) 4 digit year?

Right now I have the input of date "use date" as user entered YYYYMMDD.  I prefer to use the calendar input as it keeps the date consistent

Answer (score 1):

A Date/Time value is actually a double precision float number.

So you can take a number, and use `CDate` to represent it as a date.

```vb
? CDate(41668.0)
1/29/2014
```

The display format of the date value is a separate issue.  The same numeric date value can be displayed in whatever format you prefer.

```vb
? Format(CDate(41668.0), "yyyymmdd")
20140129

? Format(CDate(41668.0), "dd mmm yyyy")
29 Jan 2014
```

But the actual date value (the number) is unchanged --- that number doesn't get *"converted"* regardless of how it's displayed.

If your issue is that the users are working with a text value instead of a Date/Time value, you either have to convert that text to a valid Date/Time value or modify your application so they enter Date/Time values instead of text.

The second alternative is less fuss.  But if you're stuck with dates as text, you can do something like this ...

```vb
use_date = "20140129"
' transform it to a string CDate can accept ...
? Left(use_date, 4) & "-" & Mid(use_date, 5, 2) & "-" & Right(use_date, 2)
2014-01-29
' get the date from that string ...
? CDate(Left(use_date, 4) & "-" & Mid(use_date, 5, 2) & "-" & Right(use_date, 2))
1/29/2014 
' finally make it a string in your desired format ...
? Format(CDate(Left(use_date, 4) & "-" & Mid(use_date, 5, 2) & "-" & Right(use_date, 2)), "dd mmm yyyy")
29 Jan 2014
```

Comment: +1 for yet another good answer. I just hope @user3210948 realizes that the important thing is to store dates in actual `Date/Time` columns in the database and then formatting them (e.g., on forms and reports) as appropriate. Storing them as `yyyymmdd` (or `yyyy-mm-dd`) strings is awkward, and storing them as `dd mmm yyyy` strings is just foolish.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
DIM DateStr : DateStr = "20140119" 'Your date

Response.Write "DEBUG: DateStr = " & DateStr & "<br>"

'Split number so can use Date functions

DIM NewDate : NewDate = DateSerial(CInt(Mid(DateStr, 1, 4)), CInt(Mid(DateStr, 5, 2)), Mid(DateStr, 7, 2))

Response.Write "DEBUG: NewDate = " & NewDate & "<br>"

TheDate=CDate(NewDate)

Response.Write "DEBUG: CDate(NewDate) = " & TheDate & "<br>"

DIM FinalDate:  FinalDate =  DatePart("d", TheDate) & "&nbsp;"
FinalDate = FinalDate &  MonthName(Month(TheDate),1) & "&nbsp;"
FinalDate = FinalDate & DatePart("yyyy", TheDate)


Response.write "DEBUG: Required Date = " & FinalDate
```